# Vertical wood frame popped out

Tags: wood, outdoor

(Please forgive me if I am not using proper carpentry terms)

I recently noticed I have a vertical wood frame popped out. I am suspecting it is caused by thermal expansion. I can see these are vertical frame joined by sectioned wood. I am living in Seattle so a bit worried about moisture intrusion to cause more damage.

I tried to use a hammer to put it into the slot but it barely moved at all.

My questions:

1. Is it common for it to be popping out? Could it be caused by structural issues or just thermal expansion?
2. How to fix it since hammer isn't quite helping? I don't think nail is a good idea because there is no nail at all on the trim.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Is this trim around a window or door or is this some outdoor trim, maybe at the corner of the house? This is a good detail shot, but a wider picture, to help establish the overall situation would help. You can [edit] that into your question.

Comment: That looks like some kind of repair, like someone cut out a chunk of rotted wood and stuck a new piece in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to prevent damage to the wood (you have already made), and stay away from the window.

Place a piece of scrap wood on top, then wack with hammer till it is back in place. Before doing so apply some wood glue inside the opening.

You might need bigger hammer than what you have now.

Secure it with some finishing nails so it stays in place.

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty much a newbie to DIY things. I bought a 2*4 and cut it like a few inches length, and used a 20oz hammer and it seems it did the trick.

I guess my next thing is to touch up the paint once the weather is a bit warmer.

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Would use a piece of 2x4 or similar lying around.

Place the wood against that piece and wack the 2x4 with a hammer.

When back in place can use two or three finishing nails to hold it.